# How to split string by multiple characters in MSBuild 4?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-4.0

I have the following string called `MasterVersion`:

```
1.1-SNAPSHOT
```

I need to split it by the . and the - so it becomes a `string[]` array called `SplitVersion`, i.e.:

```
1
1
SNAPSHOT
```

I've tried everything I can think of including about a dozen variations of the below, with no joy:

```
<!-- doesn't work -->
<ItemGroup>
    <VersionDelimiters Include="." />
    <VersionDelimiters Include="-" />
    <SplitVersion Include="$(MasterVersion.Split(@VersionDelimiters))" />
</ItemGroup>

<!-- doesn't work either -->
<ItemGroup>
    <SplitVersion Include="$(MasterVersion.Split([`.`; `-`]))" />
</ItemGroup>
```

What obscure MSBuild syntax am I missing/mucking up?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

MSBuild 4.0 property functions cannot handle arrays (well basically), however when you do a

```
Split(`,`, `-`)
```

You are invoking the `String.Split(params string[])` overload, which requires an array (even in C# the `params` keyword will create an array behind the scene and do something like `Split(new string[] { ',', '-' })` internally).

What you could do is the following:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
 ToolsVersion="4.0">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <MasterVersion>1.1-SNAPSHOT</MasterVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <SplitVersion Include="$(MasterVersion.Replace(`-`, `.`).Split(`.`))" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="Test">
        <Message Importance="high" Text="@(SplitVersion)"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Or you could first create the (string) array to be passed to Split:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <MasterVersion>1.1-SNAPSHOT</MasterVersion>
        <Delimiters>.;-</Delimiters>
        <DelimitersArray>$(Delimiters.Split(`;`))</DelimitersArray>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <SplitVersion Include="$(MasterVersion.Split($(DelimitersArray)))" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Target Name="Test">
        <Message Importance="high" Text="@(SplitVersion)"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Which is not really better in this case ;-)

Oh, and you might want to check out [this MSDN blog entr](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/04/02/msbuild-property-functions.aspx)y for more useful information.

*Update* for a comment:

- The "content" of `SplitVersion` is technically an "array of ITaskItem", yes.
  You would deal with it however you would deal with Items (of ItemGroups);
  including things like "batching", etc.
- You cannot really "access things by index" in msbuild project files. Expressions like
  `$(SplitVersion)[0]` or `@(SplitVersion)[0]` or `@(SplitVersion[0])` don't
  do what you'd think/like. If you really would to you could assign individual 
  properties for "array elements" by "index".

Example:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <SplitVersion0>$(MasterVersion.Split($(DelimitersArray))[0])</SplitVersion0>
  <SplitVersion1>$(MasterVersion.Split($(DelimitersArray))[1])</SplitVersion1>
  <SplitVersion2>$(MasterVersion.Split($(DelimitersArray))[2])</SplitVersion2>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The array-indexing operator works here, because in this case you are still "in the context" of the .NET expression. Once that is assigned to a property (or item group) you cannot do that anymore.

Comment: Once you've done this, what is the content of `SplitVersion`? Is it an array of `ITaskItem`, presumably? How would I access the values individually, say by index?

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps

```
<ItemGroup>
    <SplitVersion Include="$(MasterVersion.Split('.','-'))" />
</ItemGroup>
```

(MSBuild should auto-convert this to array)

Comment: `error MSB4184: The expression ""1.1-SNAPSHOT".Split(., -)" cannot be evaluated. Input string was not in a correct format.`

Answer (score -2):

You're using this expression within an ItemGroup, ItemGroups are used to collect required artifacts for the build. I think you're looking for a PropertyGroup

Something like this

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <MasterVersion>1.1-SNAPSHOT</MasterVersion>
  <SplitVersion Include="$(MasterVersion.Split(`.`,`-`)" />
</PropertyGroup>
```

You should remember that Properties are referenced in MSBuild using the $ (Dollar Sign). Items are referenced using the @ (at Sign).

Depending on the Group of MasterVersion, you have to change the $ to @

Comment: That doesn't parse since you cannot have `Include` attributes on properties.

Comment: Yes thats right it should work when using it like <SplitVersion>$(MasterVersioin.Split('.','-')</SplitVersion>

Comment: No it doesn't. First of all it is missing a closing ')', secondly see my answer about array support.